# Recode multiple response variables into one in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Df <- data.frame(
       mn = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0), 
       bc = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
       bn = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0))
```

I want to recode these into a new variable.

I tried something like this

```
Df$Var[which(Df$mn %in% 1)] <- "mn"
Df$Var[which(Df$bc %in% 1)] <- "bc"
Df$Var[which(Df$bn %in% 1)] <- "bn"
```

This works but I don't get 5 mns, 5 bcs and 3 bns. It looks like one command overrides the other. I know something like this is possible in SPSS. It combines them automatically. My question is how can I do this without any overriding in R.

Comment: Assuming you have a `Df$Var` column, each line overwrites it each time depending if the condition is met. What is your expected output?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear.  Are you saying that in your new variable, it shouldn't overwrite if there's already a value there?  What would the outcome look like for this example?

Comment: Yh I see the overwriting and that is what I want to prevent. My dilemma now is in areas where mn, bc and bn are all 1, how do I tell R that the variable Var could take on any of these values. Say `Df$Var[3]` could be either mn, bn or bn. If I am counting bcs, it should be counted, if I am counting mns, it should be counted and if I am counting bns, again it should be counted.

Comment: So what should actually be in the `Var` column when two conditions apply? Both values, separated by a comma so `Var[1] = "mn, bc"`? Or something else?

Comment: @RichScriven I have no idea how to put the expected result. Honestly, I would have done it. I can only explain and that's what I have done in my comment.

Comment: You can manually write out what you expect the result to be. Perhaps this is what you're after? 
`Df$Var <- apply(Df, 1, function(x){ paste0(names(Df)[ x == 1 ], collapse = ",") })`

Answer (score 1):

```
Df$mn[which(Df$mn %in% 1)] <- "mn"
Df$bc[which(Df$bc %in% 1)] <- "bc"
Df$bn[which(Df$bn %in% 1)] <- "bn"
```

I believe this is what you want.

If you want new columns then:

```
Df <- data.frame(
       mn = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0), 
       bc = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
       bn = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0))
Df1<-Df
Df1$mn[which(Df1$mn %in% 1)] <- "mn"
Df1$bc[which(Df1$bc %in% 1)] <- "bc"
Df1$bn[which(Df1$bn %in% 1)] <- "bn"
Df<-cbind(Df,Df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Df$Var <- apply(Df, 1, function(r) {paste(names(Df)[r == 1], collapse=" ")})
```

gives

```
#   mn bc bn      Var
# 1  1  1  0    mn bc
# 2  0  1  0       bc
# 3  1  1  1 mn bc bn
# 4  1  0  1    mn bn
# 5  1  0  0       mn
# 6  1  1  1 mn bc bn
# 7  0  1  0       bc
```

Comment: Same answer as @SymbolixAU

Answer (score 1):

Similar to others no which(), %in%, or cbind() used though:

```
Df <- data.frame(
   mn = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0), 
   bc = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
   bn = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0))

Df$Var1[Df$mn == 1] <- "mn"
Df$Var2[Df$bc == 1] <- "bc"
Df$Var3[Df$bn == 1] <- "bn"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DF %>% tidyr::gather("var", "value", 1:3) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(var1 = ifelse(value==1, var, " "))
```

Or

```
Df %>% dplyr::mutate(mn1 = ifelse(mn==1, "mn", " "),
                     bc1 = ifelse(bc==1, "bc", " "),
                     bn1 = ifelse(bn==1, "bn", " "))

> Df
  mn bc bn mn1 bc1 bn1
1  1  1  0  mn  bc    
2  0  1  0      bc    
3  1  1  1  mn  bc  bn
4  1  0  1  mn      bn
5  1  0  0  mn        
6  1  1  1  mn  bc  bn
7  0  1  0      bc
```